# Android: run application in dev/prod environment?

Tags: android

I want to make development easier by implementing a configuration parameter that determines whether the app should be run in 'DEV' mode or 'PROD' mode.

I want this parameter to be accessible from any file (based on this parameter different chunks of code will be executed).

What's the most practical way to store this parameter (which isn't accessible or changeable by the user)?

*How can I access it from within the application?*

Comment: This is automatically done now by the Android tools. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with ADT 17 (IIRC), you have this automatically as part of the auto generated `BuildConfig` class.

The `DEBUG` field is always `true` when developing, but when you export a signed or unsigned apk, it is set to `false`. You can use it as:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //Debug mode
}
```

Or the other way around:

```
if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //Release mode
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a '!' in your second example?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an enum:

```
public enum BuildType {

    Release, Pilot, Debug;
}
```

And assign it to a global variable:

```
public static final BuildType BUILD_TYPE = BuildType.Debug;
```

You can even create some methods in the enum that allow you 
switch over very specific parts of  your application.

Now you can do stuff like this:

```
if (MyApplication.BUILD_TYPE != BuildType.Release) {
    // some code that does not go in the release
}
```

Comment: Should I put this into a seperate class to make it extendible later on? And to seperate the logic?

Comment: We have a class that extends Application, we did put it there.

Answer (score 1):

A static field in one of your Activity ? Or I am missing something ?

```
public static boolean isDev = true;
```

You can set it in the `onCreate` of your main activity.

Comment: Will this parameter be available accross different activities? I'll have to use MainActivity.isDev, correct?

Comment: As soon as it is static you can always refer to the field with `MyActivity.isDev`. Nevermind the fact that the activity is running or not

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class and add your variable there. 
Also you can add some methods which will display some details about your app in dev mode.

```
public class Console{
  public final static boolean isDev = true;
  public static error(String tag, String msg){
    if(isDev){
      Log.e(TAG, msg);
    }
  }
}
```